# How to get XML namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I tried using this code: [C#]

```
var textReader = new XmlTextReader(path);
if (textReader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
{
  //...
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe version="2.00" Id="NFe31130317194994450127550012302143751002144567">
<ide>
//continue...
```

But my code always returns "" ...

**Is there a easy way to get XML namespace?**

Comment: `new XmlTextReader()` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. You should be using `XmlReader.Create()` instead. Depending on what else you're doing with the XML, you'll find LINQ to XML much easier than playing with XmlReaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will return the namespaceUri of the current node.

Try to advance in the xml stream:

```
var textReader = new XmlTextReader(path);
while(reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) textReader.Read();
if (textReader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice linq method:

```
XDocument z = XDocument.Parse(s);
var result = z.Root.Attributes().
    Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).
    GroupBy(a => a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None ? String.Empty : a.Name.LocalName,
            a => XNamespace.Get(a.Value)).
    ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                 g => g.First());
```

Find this method and more at [hanselmans site: Get namespaces from an XML Document with XPathDocument and LINQ to XML](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx)

Then just loop through the dictionary as desired.