# how to get xml namespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, namespaces

my `xml` is

```
<message to="to_test" from="from_test">
    <test xmlns="google:mobile:data">
        {"message":"test_message"}
    </test>
</message>
```

i get the value `{"message":"test_message"}` by using the function `getChildText("pcm")`. But i tried to retrieve the namespace `xmlns` value.

I tried the following [How to get XML namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652624/how-to-get-xml-namespace) , [How to get specific XML namespace in XQuery in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064078/how-to-get-specific-xml-namespace-in-xquery-in-sql-server) with no luck, it shows me `is not function error` what i'm doing wrong?

I forgot to mention, I'm currently staring work with **node.js**.

**update**

the above xml output is  `xmpp stanza`.

Here i'm getting the `attrs` using the following.

`stanza.attrs.to` gives me `to_test`.

`stanza.attrs.from` gives me `from_test`.

`stanza.getChildText("test")` gives me `{"message":"test_message"}`

I tried to get the `xmlns` using

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var documents = parser.parseFromString(stanza, 'text/xml');
    var response = documents.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("test");
    var sunrise = response[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("[Namespace URI]", "test")[0].getAttribute("xmlns");
    console.log(sunrise);
```

here i got

```
[xmldom error]  element parse error: TypeError: source.indexOf is not a function @#[line:0,col:undefined]
```

Comment: I was able to get the namespace using getAttribute: `document.querySelector('test').getAttribute('xmlns')` shows "google:mobile:data"

Comment: What XML module are you using? How are you reading the file? Show us the code that isn't working.

Comment: I'm working with `xmpp`. the output is from `stanza` and i need to parse it

Comment: Show us the code that isn't working.

Comment: sorry for the delay.. @Quentin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the standard browser's DOM parser, you can do the following:

```
var txt = "<message><test xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\"> {\"message\":\"test_message\"}</test></message>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
ns = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test")[0].namespaceURI
```

I have tested with Chrome and IE and it works.

Comment: i got `[xmldom error] element parse error: TypeError: source.indexOf is not a function @#[line:0,col:undefined]`

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar error -- in my case it was because I had passed something besides a string to "parseFromString". Could this be the problem? It looks like "stanza" is not a string.